# Send single emails using FuelSDK-Node with Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soap-client, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Is it possible to replicate the [sendSingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm) from the Salesforce docs using the Marketing Cloud [Fuel SOAP Clien](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/FuelSDK-Node-SOAP/)t (for Node.js)

Answer (score 0):

`sendEmail` in the doc you're quoting refers to the "main" [Salesforce platform](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/starting_force_com/starting_understanding_arch). Fuel SOAP client is for Marketing Cloud, a Salesforce application that (unfortunately) does not reside on the "main" Salesforce platform.

If you're looking to send email from the "main" Salesforce platform, there are a variety of clients available. For Node.js, a popular client is [jsforce](https://github.com/jsforce). Unfortunately it doesn't support [sendEmail](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/136). An alternative is a Node.js client that is tailored to invoke any SOAP web service. Popular options: [ws.js](https://github.com/yaronn/ws.js) or [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap). You would need to grab the access token and a SOAP envelope from the documentation and implement it using one of the clients above.

On the other hand, if you are after an equivalent of generating a single email message in Marketing Cloud, you first need to understand *how* you're going to do this in Marketing Cloud. The closest option might be a [triggered send](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_triggered_emails.htm&type=5)...but the devil is in the details, you should review the requirements and appropriate implementation options with your Marketing Cloud specialist. Marketing Cloud SDKs/clients are [available](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/index-sdk.htm) for various stacks including Node.js; there's a section on triggered sends with examples.

For very Salesforce-specific questions, you could also consult [Salesforce SE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com)